# How to split a file by every n lines?

Tags: python

I know to split a file by lines, you can do `f.readlines()`, but what if I was trying to split a file by every n lines? For example, I have a file

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
```

instead of looping through it line by line, I want to loop through it by every two lines, so it would output

```
line1
line2

line3
line4
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

when you loop, you can get the index of the line with `enumerate()` and split there

```py
collection = []
sub_collection = []
with open("test.txt") as fh:
    for index, line in enumerate(fh, 1):  # file-likes are iterable by-lines
        sub_collection.append(line)
        if index % 2 == 0:  # modulus is 0 every Nth line
            collection.append("".join(sub_collection))
            sub_collection = []
```

```py
>>> collection
['line1\nline2\n', 'line3\nline4\n', 'line5\nline6\n', 'line7\nline8\n']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to chunk an array next way

```py
def chunked(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]
```

And then use it with `readlines`

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
for l in chunked(f.readlines(), 2):
  # do anything with chunk
f.close()
```